# Move toolbar to the top in TinyMCE Simple theme

Tags: tinymce

How do I move the toolbar to the top in TinyMCE Simple theme? Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

---

**Note:** The instructions below are valid for TinyMCE 3.x. TinyMCE 4.x is available now and you should probably use it instead. See http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration for more information.

---

The toolbar can only be moved to top when using `theme : advanced` in TinyMCE. There is no `theme_simple_toolbar_location` but a `theme_advanced_toolbar_location`. See documentation here http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:theme_advanced_toolbar_location.

What you can do is to serve the editor as `theme : advanced` and then customize the buttons by using the `theme_advanced_buttons_1_n` property. It's documented here http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:theme_advanced_buttons_1_n.

#### Example:

The code in the example is not tested, but it should work. It will show an editor with the buttons for Bold, Italic and Underline at the top.

```
tinyMCE.init({
  mode : "textareas",
  theme : "advanced",
  theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
  theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline",
  theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
  theme_advanced_buttons3 : ""
});
```

So the answer would be: one cannot move the buttons when using `theme : simple`.

Comment: This is true. Since you haven't specified any original code, the docs also mention that the layout manager must be set to "SimpleLayout" this is the default, but since no code was shown by @Honza Pokorny then just make sure that there is either no layout manager specified which would default to SimpleLayout or  you are not using another layout manager. This would case it not too work.

Comment: the links are broken, please fix

Comment: @Alexei: TinyMCE wiki has been moved to a new location. I have updated to the links to the correct location.

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you have to edit the editor_template.js which is inside themes/simple folder.

Following is the code with the change to bring the toolbar on top.

```
(function() {
    var a = tinymce.DOM;
    tinymce.ThemeManager.requireLangPack("simple");
    tinymce.create("tinymce.themes.SimpleTheme", {
        init: function(c, d) {
            var e = this,
                b = ["Bold", "Italic", "Underline", "Strikethrough", "InsertUnorderedList", "InsertOrderedList"],
                f = c.settings;
            e.editor = c;
            c.contentCSS.push(d + "/skins/" + f.skin + "/content.css");
            c.onInit.add(function() {
                c.onNodeChange.add(function(h, g) {
                    tinymce.each(b, function(i) {
                        g.get(i.toLowerCase()).setActive(h.queryCommandState(i))
                    })
                })
            });
            a.loadCSS((f.editor_css ? c.documentBaseURI.toAbsolute(f.editor_css) : "") || d + "/skins/" + f.skin + "/ui.css")
        },
        renderUI: function(h) {
            var e = this,
                i = h.targetNode,
                b, c, d = e.editor,
                f = d.controlManager,
                g, tbody;
            i = a.insertAfter(a.create("span", {
                id: d.id + "_container",
                "class": "mceEditor " + d.settings.skin + "SimpleSkin"
            }), i);
            i = g = a.add(i, "table", {
                cellPadding: 0,
                cellSpacing: 0,
                "class": "mceLayout"
            });
            tbody = c = a.add(i, "tbody");
            i = b = a.add(a.add(i, "td"), "div", {
                "class": "mceIframeContainer"
            });
            i = a.add(a.add(c, "tr", {
                "class": "last"
            }), "td", {
                "class": "mceToolbar mceLast",
                align: "center"
            });
            c = e.toolbar = f.createToolbar("tools1");
            c.add(f.createButton("bold", {
                title: "simple.bold_desc",
                cmd: "Bold"
            }));
            c.add(f.createButton("italic", {
                title: "simple.italic_desc",
                cmd: "Italic"
            }));
            c.add(f.createButton("underline", {
                title: "simple.underline_desc",
                cmd: "Underline"
            }));
            c.add(f.createButton("strikethrough", {
                title: "simple.striketrough_desc",
                cmd: "Strikethrough"
            }));
            c.add(f.createSeparator());
            c.add(f.createButton("undo", {
                title: "simple.undo_desc",
                cmd: "Undo"
            }));
            c.add(f.createButton("redo", {
                title: "simple.redo_desc",
                cmd: "Redo"
            }));
            c.add(f.createSeparator());
            c.add(f.createButton("cleanup", {
                title: "simple.cleanup_desc",
                cmd: "mceCleanup"
            }));
            c.add(f.createSeparator());
            c.add(f.createButton("insertunorderedlist", {
                title: "simple.bullist_desc",
                cmd: "InsertUnorderedList"
            }));
            c.add(f.createButton("insertorderedlist", {
                title: "simple.numlist_desc",
                cmd: "InsertOrderedList"
            }));
            c.renderTo(i);
            i = c = a.add(i, "tbody");
            i = a.add(c, "tr");
            return {
                iframeContainer: b,
                editorContainer: d.id + "_container",
                sizeContainer: g,
                deltaHeight: -20
            }
        },
        getInfo: function() {
            return {
                longname: "Simple theme",
                author: "Moxiecode Systems AB",
                authorurl: "http://tinymce.moxiecode.com",
                version: tinymce.majorVersion + "." + tinymce.minorVersion
            }
        }
    });
    tinymce.ThemeManager.add("simple", tinymce.themes.SimpleTheme)
})();
```

Answer (score -3):

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "simple"
    theme_simple_toolbar_location : "top"
});
```

The important bit is the "toolbar_location" parameter.

Comment: Did you try this before posting here? It's not in the documentation and it's not working.